# Java Program that loads text documents and ranks them based on amount of repeated words - keep getting file not found error

Tags: java, stack, rank

I'm creating a Java program that can load different text documents (in this case, the first chapter or so of four different novels) and then print them out in order of their vocabulary ranks. In other words, they are ranked based on how many times words are repeated in the chapter. This program includes three classes:

hw5.java:

```
public class hw5 {
    //main method
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        //stores user entered data
        String userInput = "";
        //Scanner class object created
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Write a file name to include in your ranks, '?' to list ranks, and ! to exit program");
        //Accepts user choice and loops while user choice is not "!"
        while(!userInput.equals("!")) {
            System.out.print(">> ");
            userInput = in.next();
            //if user choice is "!", the program stops
            if (userInput.equals("!")) {
                System.out.println("\nGood Bye :)");
            }
            //if user choice is "?", the program stops
            else if(userInput.equals("?")) {
                //calls printRanks() method from StoryRanker to display file name and word count
                StoryRanker.printRanks();
            }
            //Otherwise it's a file name
            else {
                //Uses default constructor to pass the file name to Story class
                Story myStory = new Story(userInput);
                //if getWordCount method from Story is greater than 0, call addStory() method from StoryRanker and pass the object
                if(myStory.getWordCount()>0) {
                    StoryRanker.addStory(myStory);
                }
            }
            }
        }
}
```

Story.java:

```
public class Story {
        //stores word count
        int wordCount;
        //stores file name
        String title;
        //Scanner class object for reading file
        Scanner fileRead;
        //file object
        File file;
        
        //Constructor for receiving file name
        Story(String fileName){
            //initializes file object by file name
            file = new File(fileName);
            //extracts file extension
            title = fileExtension(fileName);
        }
        
        //Method that returns number of words in the file
        int getWordCount() {
            //try block
            try {
                //file is read
                fileRead = new Scanner(file);
                //Checks for data
                while(fileRead.hasNextLine()) {
                    //Word is read
                    fileRead.next();
                    //wordCount increases
                    wordCount++;
                }
                //File is closed
                fileRead.close();
            }
            //Catch for FileNotFoundException
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("File Not Found");
            }
            //returns wordCount
        return wordCount;
        }
        
        //method that returns file name from complete file name with extension
        static String fileExtension(String str) {
            //null case
            if(str == null) {
                return null;
            }
            //gets position of last "."
            int pos = str.lastIndexOf(".");
            //if there's no "." return the string as it is
            if(pos == -1) {
                return str;
            }
            //returns string up to "."
            return str.substring(0,pos);
        }
}
```

and StoryRanker.java:

```
class Data {
    //Stores file name
    String fileName;
    //stores word count
    int wordCount;
    }

class MyNewStack{
    //stores 100 file names and word count
    Data myData[] = new Data[100];
    //points to top
    int top;
    //stores length
    int length;
    
    //default constructor
    void MyNewStack() {
    top = -1;
    length = 0;
    }
    
    //Returns false if top = -1, but otherwise returns true
    boolean isEmpty() {
        if(top == -1) {
            return false;
            }
        else {
            return true;
            }
        }
    
    //method pushes object to stack
    void push (Data d) {
        //Checks is stack is full
        if (top == 99) {
            System.out.println("Stack is full");
        }
        //if stack isn't full
        else {
            //increases top position of stack by one
            ++top;
            //instantiates the array top index position
            myData[top] = new Data();
            //Stores file name and word count
            myData[top].fileName = d.fileName;
            myData[top].wordCount = d.wordCount;
            //increases length by one
            length++;
            }
        }
        
    //method to pop the stack top position
    Data pop() {
        //if stack top is less than zero, the stack is empty
        if(top<0) {
            System.out.println("Stack Underflow.");
            return null;
        }
        //Otherwise, decrease length by one and return stack top position object
        else {
            length--;
            return myData[top--];
        }
    }
    
    //method to return stack a position
    Data peek(int a) {
        //if stack top is less than zero, the stack is empty
        if(top < 0) {
            System.out.println("Stack underflow.");
            return null;
        }
        //otherwise returns stack a position object
        else {
            return myData[a];
        }
    }
}

//establish StoryRanker public class
public class StoryRanker {
    
    //MyNewStack class objects
    static MyNewStack stack1 = new MyNewStack();
    static MyNewStack stack2 = new MyNewStack();
    
    //Data class object
    static Data d = new Data();
    
    //Method to add file name and word count to stack
    public static void addStory(Story myStory) {
        //Extract data from myStory and store it in Data object
        d.fileName = myStory.title;
        d.wordCount = myStory.wordCount;
        //checks if stack is not empty
        if(!stack1.isEmpty()) {
            //Push object to first stack
            stack1.push(d);
        }
        else {
            //loops until first stack top position
            for(int a = 0; a <= stack1.top; a++) {
                //if stack word count is less than current file word count
                if(stack1.peek(a).wordCount < myStory.wordCount) {
                    //Push object to second stack
                    stack2.push(stack1.pop());
                }
            }
            //puush current object to first stack
            stack1.push(d);
            //for loop until second stack top position
            for(int a = 0; a < stack2.length; a++) {
                //extracts second stack object and pushes it to first stack
                stack1.push(stack2.pop());
            }
        }
    }
    
    //Method to display first stack contents
    public static void printRanks() {
        //loops until first stack top position
        for(int a = 0; a <= stack1.top; a++) {
            System.out.println((a+1)+ ": " + stack1.peek(a).fileName + ", size = " + stack1.peek(a).wordCount);
        }
    
    }
}
```

And here is what it should look like when running the program:

```
Write a file name to include your ranks, '?' to list ranks, and ! to exit program
>>the_boy_who_lived.txt
>>?

1: the_boy_who_lived, size= 392.

>>dracula_chapter1.txt
>>?

1: dracula_chapter1, size= 1309.
2: the_boy_who_lived, size= 392.

>>!

Good Bye :)
```

The problem I'm running into is that whenever I enter one of the files I am using, it keeps returning "File Not Found." I've tried typing in the entire address, including the .txt at the end, and nothing seems to be going through. Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: A path which is just a file name is a "relative path" -- the operating system looks for the file in the working directory of the current program. So if you want to type just the filename you need to make sure that it's in the same directory you were in when you started your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Story(String fileName){
    //initializes file object by file name
    String directory = "C:\\Users\\stlp\\IdeaProjects\\StoryCount\\src.\\" + fileName + ".txt";
    file = new File(directory);
    //extracts file extension
    title = fileExtension(fileName);
}
```

Replace the first string of directory with your actual absolute directory. Make sure to include the double slashes. When inputting the file name, you want to put in just the name as the .txt is appended already.

Comment: This is definitely helpful. The only problem is now I'm running into an issue where it won't let me load two of the four text files I'm using for this program.

Comment: Could you clarify what your directory with the text files look like?

Comment: C:\\Users\\myname\\eclipse-workspace\\program\\src\\excerpt_from_the_winds_of_winter.txt

Comment: Are you still getting a file not found exception or is it a different error?